# code didn't enter in script part in mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this code in my mvc4 project and it didn't work 
i want to enforce it to enter in the script code to call the uploader function in external file and i take link to this file in my view but it didn't enter the script part even didn't show the alert or console.log or debugger
in view

```
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid editor">
            <input type="file" name="files" id="upload" />
            <script>
                alert("hellllllllllllllllllo");
                var paths = new Array();
                var type = new fileTypesFun();
                Uploader(type.all, "upload", function (e) {
                    onSuccess(e)
                }, function (e) {
                    onError(e)
                }, function (e) {
                    onRemove(e)
                }, true);

                function onSuccess(e) {
                    paths.push(e.replay);
                }

                function onError(e) {
                    alert('error' + JSON.stringify(e));
                }

                function onRemove(e) {
                    var elm = event.target;
                    file_name = elm.previousElementSibling.title;

                    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                        if (paths[i].indexOf(file_name) != -1) {
                            paths.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why `<script>` part is inside div... why not in `<head>` of html?

Comment: just writing the script inside the div will not allow it to enter inside the script.
you need to explicitly call the script on blur or click

Comment: What is `fileTypesFun()` and what is `Uploader`??

Comment: both is function in external file i already take link for it @Jaimin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just writing the script inside the div will not allow it to enter inside the script. you need to explicitly call the script on blur or click